# Jailbroken iPhone dev

Tags: iphone, perl, ios4, core-location

I have had great success with running perl on my jailbroken iPhone 4: http://coredev.nl/

Now I would like to play with more functionality like CoreLocation. I'd like to query some GPS and orientation data. I do have OSX running in a VM and so I am able to compile iOS apps in Xcode. However I've been having a difficult time learning the ins and outs so far, and I would really like to have some way of hacking together something more UNIX-y that I'm comfortable with, like the server/client networking perl scripts I have been writing.

For example I can easily download some sample code from Apple, load it up in Xcode, compile after switching off the code signing and whatnot, then SCP the app directory into /Applications, restart springboard, and bam it's on the homescreen, I was really happy to have all of this working (through a virtual machine no less!), but this is actually overkill.

What if I want an executable that I can run from perl, which simply spits some GPS coordinates out on stdout? I understand I'll need to use CoreLocation API, but I shouldn't have to deal with MVC, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the p5-GPS* packages?

http://coredev.nl/cydia/dists/iphone/main/binary-iphoneos-arm/